# Ending an interactive program causes infinite loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
//Testing numbers for primality

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int n;          //User input number
int i;          //Input number will be divided by i
int count;      

count = 0;

cout << endl;   

while(n != 'q') {

    cout << "#: ";
    cin >> n;       

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {   
                    //increase the divisor until it's equal to n                
        if(n % i == 0) {
             count++;
        }       
        //If there is no remainder, count increases by 1. Since prime numbers are only divisible by 1 and themselves, count will be exactly 2 in the case of a prime number.

    }

    if(count == 2) {
        cout << "   1\n";       //1 = yes prime

    }else if(count != 2) {      
        cout << "   0\n";       //0 = not prime

    }

    count = 0;

}

if(n == 'q') {
    return(0);
}
}
```

Here I am testing numbers to see if they are prime. Count increases every time the remainder of division n/i is 0 so when count=2, output is 1 for yes, otherwise 0 for no. I've gotten the program to test as many numbers as I want correctly during a session, but I am trying to create an escape sequence.

I tried using the condition (n=='q') for quit, but when I input q, the program loops infinitely. I tried putting a break; statement for this condition within the while loop but the result is the same. I am guessing this problem has to do with char-int/int-char conversion. Can someone hint to me how I can create a working exit sequence?

Comment: Why not make your exit condition a special number that does not make sense for your program like 0 or -1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Infinite loop after receiving input and testing to see if it's an int in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618473/infinite-loop-after-receiving-input-and-testing-to-see-if-its-an-int-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no code that can *read* a `q`. Your input logic only accepts a number. You then test if that number is equivalent to a `q` character. The equivalent integer to the letter `q` is 113. If you try that, it will quit.

Since you really want to input a number *or* a letter, you'll need to write input logic that can accept either. Then you'll need to check what input you got, and then process it accordingly.

Comment: Answer should mention stream state, how it got there, and how to correctly handle that.  And then 'while(std::cin >> n){'

Comment: Woohoo old post bump! as Mooing Duck sort of mentioned, you can use `cin >> inttype` to try to read an integer.  If it fails, that would mean there's something in the buffer that's not an integer.  You would need to first reset the stream and subsequently try to read a string from it.  This would succeed, and you'd be able to compare the string to `"q"`, `"quit"`, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

'q' is a character. `n` is an integer.

Checking whether `n == 'q'` will implicitly convert 'q' to the `int` type - so, your program will exit if you put in the number 113 (ASCII for 'q').

You probably want to use a number out of the bounds of conventional input (such as a negative value, or zero) as your termination condition.

Side note: you did not *initialize* `n` before checking it in the `while` loop. It is possible for `n` to start with any random garbage, so some percentage of the time your program will spontaneously exit without running the loop at all. You should compile your code with `-Wall -Wextra` (if using `gcc`) to have the compiler warn you about obvious stuff like that.

Comment: hint: infinite loop with a stream means the stream is in a bad state.

Comment: @MooingDuck What? He only reads from `cin` into `n`, which is of type `int`. The reason there's an "infinite loop" is just that he has a `while` loop whose termination condition he didn't hit (because he misunderstood what exactly he was checking). Take another look at the code.

Comment: Upon entering anything that isnt a valid integer, his code will repeat for the _previous_ (or undefined) value of n indefinitely, because 'std::cin' will have its badbit set and perform no further input.